# Need to upload excel file in jmeter using selenium webdriver plugin script

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

If anyone pls provide the code(WDS code) snippet of how to upload file in   application using Jmeter selenium plugin

Sample Code snippet

In jmeter webdriver i don't know how to write that particular format.

I know about how to write selenium using robot class.

If anyone provide code snippet of upload file using robot class for jmeter webdriver plugin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class is a big anti-pattern especially when it comes to JMeter with its multi-threaded nature because the browser window **must have focus**

I would rather recommend using [WebElement.sendKeys() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...)), something like:

```
element = wdsbrowser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id("your-upload-file-input-id"))
element.sendKeys("c:/somefolder/your-file.xslx")
```

I'm also under impression that you're misusing the WebDriver Sampler, according to the [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

so I think you need to create the main load (including file uploads) using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers (given you properly [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) it won't be any difference from the system under test perspective).

WebDriver Sampler is designed to collect frontend performance metrics (which JMeter cannot give you) to enrich your test results, using Selenium for performance testing is [not recommended](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/) by its vendor.

Comment: While recording i am not able to capture upload file transaction. My file path is also placed bin folder only that's why i am looking for selenium script for that particular transaction...